# Python + Google App Engine, Window.Open

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

Ok... new to python and I'm not sure I really understand how my site pages should be setup. Here's the scenario:
I've got a report that outputs to an HTML table, with some charted data on a page. I want to open a new browser window instance with a clean, downladable HTML version of that page. In dotnet, I'd just use the JS function window.open() to pop up a web form, pass in a few querystring parameters and build the new page accordingly.

I've tried the equivalent logic with Python, but with no luck. I can only get HTML pages to load in the pop up. When I can get the new .py page to load, the python code is spit out on the screen, it is not parsed by the interpreter. Plus, even if I do get it working, I'm not sure I know how to pass values between the 2 pages.

Is it possible that I only use my main.py file to run code out of?

Answer (score 2):

You're somehow making this harder than it should be. You do exactly the same thing in Python as you would in .net: just open a new window with the relevant URL, including any query parameters. The browser doesn't know or care what language your backend code is written in: it just deals in URLs.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Unfortuntely,as I mentioned, whenver I load the .py page in the new window it just dumps all the code out like I'm loading a .txt file... nothing is parsed.

Comment: But I don't understand why you're trying to load a .py file. You should be loading a URL, which your server code maps to a py file, just like the original page.